# Urlrewrite with tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, redirect

I'm trying to redirect two urls to the main page but I cannot get it going. Here's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<display-name>Ventanilla Virtual</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml, classpath:applicationContextWeb.xml, classpath:applicationContextWebService.xml, classpath:applicationContext-quartz.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Filtros de redes sociales -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Push Servlet - listens for user sessions -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.richfaces.webapp.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/__richfaces_push</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- setups servlet-mapping in RichFaces configuration -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.push.handlerMapping</param-name>
    <param-value>/__richfaces_push</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.push.initializeOnStartup</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.useBlocking</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

And here's my urlrewrite.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite>

<rule match-type="wildcard">
    <from>/ventanillavirtual/twitter/**</from>
    <to type="forward">/ventanillavirtual</to>
</rule>
<rule match-type="wildcard">
    <from>/ventanillavirtual/facebook/**</from>
    <to type="forward">/ventanillavirtual</to>
</rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

The url that I'd like to redirect is, for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/ventanillavirtual/rs/facebook/125
```

to:

```
http://localhost:8080/ventanillavirtual
```

Any ideas?? I've been struggling a lot with this